# ¿Cómo consultar cuándo y si un nodo fail-over se ha activado en Azure Traffic Manager?

Tags: azure

He configurado un **Azure Web Site** por duplicado en dos regiones distintas y he configurado el servicio de **Azure Traffic Manager** en modo *Fail-Over*. Llevo ya tiempo con esta configuración funcionando pero no sé si realmente ha fallado alguna vez el nodo principal o cuántas veces ha ocurrido. Si el número de fallos es muy bajo, me plantearía descartar la redundancia y me ahorraría tener que desplegar por duplicado, aparte del ahorro en el precio.

La cuestión es que al tener configurada la monitorización, el servicio del **Traffic Manager** realiza chequeos periódicos para comprobar si los servicios están activos y activar el *fail-over* si fuera necesario, pero aparentemente no pone a disposición de los usuarios esa información, al menos en la gráfica sólo se ve el número de peticiones DNS a lo largo del tiempo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podría configurar un monitor DNS externo, pero normalmente suelen guardar *si tuvo o no una respuesta correcta* o *si la IP coincidió con una específica*, no he visto nunca que guarde el alias de DNS CNAME (myservice.trafficmanager.azure.net => myservice-euwest.azurewebsites.net, por ejemplo).

¿Alguien sabe si se puede acceder al histórico de estados de cada end-point? ¿Quizás desde la API del **Traffic Manager**?

Comment: Jorge, he dado mi voto para cerrar está pregunta ya que no veo que esté relacionada a Programación, estos son temas de configuración

Comment: En enSO hay otros sitios para tener estas preguntas pero en esSO (acá) no tenemos, por eso voto para dejarla abierta.

Comment: @CésarBustíos al inicio pensé lo mismo que tu, pero desafortunadamente no tenemos donde realizar este tipo de preguntas, podemos dejarla abierta y en un futuro migrar la pregunta cuando exista el sitio adecuado.

Comment: @Elenasys el sitio adecuado seria esperar que SE cree un sitio en español para Server Fault o Super User, no he visto si quiera que exista la propuesta. Yo no tengo problemas en que existan estas preguntas, solo trataba de hacer que no se empiece a desviar el sitio ;)

Comment: @CésarBustíos Tienes mucha razón, estoy de acuerdo contigo, acabo de agregar una propuesta: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174/sitio-tipo-serverfault-o-superuser

Comment: @JorgePestano, pudiste verificar el tema de las alertas?

Answer (score 3):

En realidad yo iría un paso más atrás.

Entiendo que estás usando el Traffic manager para tener failover a través de diferentes regiones. Sin embargo ahora mismo estás estimando desactivar la redundancia lo cual sería un craso error por varios motivos.

1. Si no tienes más de 1 instancia Azure no te garantiza el acuerdo de servicio
2. Tu aplicación no es apta para poner en producción, mucho menos en un escenario de nube pública

Entonces lo que deberías hacer es configurar la escalabilidad y failover con el mismo servicio de websites habilitando más de una instancia directamente desde la configuración de escalabilidad.

Tratándose de nube la recomendación es siempre iniciar con recursos modestos y a medida que la aplicación lo necesite entonces ir incrementando los recursos usados, no lo contrario: comenzar grande e ir reduciendo.

Por demás está de decir la configuración del failover desde el propio servicio de websites es de lejos mucho más sencilla que hacerlo desde el traffic manager, que desde luego es más 'flexible' pero a un costo de complejidad mayor.

Para mirar el registro del Traffic Manager revisa este artículo en la documentación de azure

[About Traffic Manager Monitoring](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-monitoring/)

Debes configurar el monitoreo y el sistema de alertas para usarlo en adelante, es decir para verificar datos  pasados no hay nada que hacer.

De hecho la idea allí es que puedas hacer uso del sistema de alertas para saber cuando uno de los nodos falla.

### Alertas en Azure

1) En el portal vas a cada uno de los websites que vas a monitorear, allí vas a Tools

[image: Tools]

2) Allí debes buscar **Alertas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3) Seleccionas adicionar alertas, adicionar nueva

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4) Y allí configuras la alerta, preferiblemente coincidiendo con el/los criterios que usas para disparar el failover

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: JuanK, el acuerdo de servicio para App Service (Web Apps) no indica que debes tener más de una instancia: https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/support/legal/sla/app-service/v1_1/ (si lo hace el de Cloud Services, por ejemplo). Lo que indica es el tipo de aplicación y el nivel de servicio mínimo para garantizarlo.

Comment: Tienes razón eso solo aplica para MV.

Comment: En efecto, empezamos con un único web site en una región, con la mala suerte de que al poco tiempo hubo una caida y tomamos la decisión de habilitar el Traffic Manager, estándo ahora en el punto en el que no hemos sufrido caídas desde hace tiempo y ya no sabemos si es por que la caida inicial no se ha vuelto a repetir o por que el Traffic Manager ha hecho bien su trabajo, y he ahí mi pregunta... En la información que enlazas *no dice cómo obtener el histórico de disponibilidad*.

Comment: @JorgePestano Debes configurarlo para usarlo en adelante, es decir para verificar datos  pasados no hay nada que hacer. De hecho la idea allí es que puedas hacer uso del sistema de alertas para saber cuando uno de los nodos falla. -> Actualizado en la respuesta.

Comment: @JuanK, no hay una opción para activar las alertas en el portal de administración (si alguien sabe cómo, lo ideal sería dar los pasos para activar las alertas) y el enlace que provees es sobre *cómo funciona internamente* la monitorización, pero esa información no está accesible (al menos a día de hoy) desde la interfaz de usuario. Mi pregunta es si alguien conoce cómo se accede desde la API, que imagino que sí que tendrá esa información disponible.

Comment: @JorgePestano He adicionado detalles acerca de como hacerlo, crei que habia puesto un link que describe este proceso pero por alguna razón terminé poniendo otro. saludos.

Comment: @JorgePestano pudiste verificar el tema de las alertas?